# What's the difference between angular 2.0.0-rc4 vs Angular 2.0.0

Tags: angular

I am working on the `Angular 2.0.0 rc-4` documentation but previous day's `Angular Release 2.0.0` .How I configure my app in `2.0.0.`

> What's the main difference in it ?
>   Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. The main difference came in RC5: NgModule.

Comment: **2.0.0-rc4** is release candidate 4 and **2.0.0** is the final release on 14th sep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above you have to go thru the changelog
http://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

In this change log you need to mainly focus on breaking changes.

Just to summarize, if you would like to migrated from rc4 to final:

1. You need to create one module (NgModule) at App level
2. That module will bootstrap you app.component
3. In the declarations section of the module you have to add all the Components, Directives, Pipes that you have created in your applications.
4. In the providers section, you have to add all the services
5. Also you have to remove directive and pipe list from each component meta data as those are now removed.

I guess now you are good to go with final version.
Later on, I would suggest that you can refactor your code to have modules for each features.

Comment: Thanks Dashing Dev that's help full for me :)

Comment: If answer helps you then could you please mark the answer correct so that it can help others

Comment: Ok, I will do this

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be many changes including ngmodules and how to bootstrap. Please check breaking changes in the [release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and [blog post about rc5/ng-modules](http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html)

Comment: Angular is constantly updating