# How to Convert Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 Visual Studio 2015 Project to Angular 4.0.0

Tags: angular, package.json

Package.json

```
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

This is My package.json for Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 with typescript:"1.8.10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With  typescript 1.8.10. You are not able to upgrade to angular 4, so you need to install latest version of TypeScript form [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True)

Then replace package version from the below package.json file
https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json

And final your using Release candidate 4 version of angular so you need to change some code. Ref below URL
[What's the difference between angular 2.0.0-rc4 vs Angular 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549822/whats-the-difference-between-angular-2-0-0-rc4-vs-angular-2-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Just update dependencies in the package.json to version 4.0.1 and run

```
npm install
```

There is no breaking changes and all the code in 4.x is backwards compatible with 2.x branch, but 4.x does deprecate certain things (they will continue to work until 5.x branch)

You can also automate the process of updating package.json by using npm-check-updates
https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates